# Will PHP 5.4.35 runs on CentOS 6.9 be worked normally when upgrading CentOS 6.9 to CentOS 7.5?

Tags: php, centos

I would like to upgrade CentOS 6.9 to CentOS 7.5.

I am running PHP 5.4.35 on CentOS6.9.

I want to know if PHP 5.4.35 will work with no problem in CentOS 7.5

Comment: Why do you want to keep PHP5.4. It is very old now and well past its sell by date

Comment: Sorry i was wrong.I want to copy php files of version 5.4.35 in CentOS 6.9 to 5.4.45-17 version in CentOS 7.5.